# why parsing with jq returns null?

Tags: json, bash, parsing, extract, jq

i am trying to extract values of 3 fields (status, id, name) from my json file by using jq tool, here is my json:

cat parse.json

```
{
  "stream": {
    "_id": 65675798730520654496,
    "broadcast_platform": "live",
    "community_id": "",
    "community_ids": [],
    "average_fps": 60.0247524752,
    "delay": 0,
    "created_at": "2018-09-26T07:25:38Z",
    "is_playlist": false,
    "stream_type": "live",
    "preview": {
      "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_versuta-80x4512wdfqf.jpg",
    },
    "channel": {
      "mature": true,
      "status": "status",
      "broadcaster_language": "ru",
      "broadcaster_software": "",
      "_id": 218025408945123423423445,
      "name": "djvbsdhvsdvasdv",
      "created_at": "2011-04-17T17:31:36.091604Z",
      "updated_at": "2018-09-26T09:49:04.434245Z",
      "partner": true,
      "video_banner": null,
      "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/25c2bec3-95b8-4347-aba0-128b3b913b0d-profile_banner-480.png",
      "profile_banner_background_color": "",
      "views": 103911737,
      "followers": 446198,
      "broadcaster_type": "",
      "description": "",
      "private_video": false,
      "privacy_options_enabled": false
    }
  }
}
```

online json validators say that it is valid, when i try to get some field it return `null`

cat parse.json | jq '.channel'

```
null
```

cat parse.json | jq '.channel.status'

```
null
```

what am i doing wrong guys ?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid because of a comma at `preview.small`. You have a top level object `.stream`, so do you mean to do `jq '.stream.channel' parse.json`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON object has a top-level field "stream" You need to access "stream" to access the other sub-properties, e.g. `channel`:

```
jq '.stream.channel.status' parse.json
```

You can also do `cat parse.json | jq '.stream.channel.status'`.

Your example JSON is also invalid because the `stream.preview.small` property has a trailing comma. Simply removing that comma will make it valid, though.

Comment: ty u dude i really missed that

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the invalid JSON, you could use a JSON rectifier such as `hjson`; to avoid any hassles associated with identifying the relevant paths, you could use `..|objects`.  Thus for example:

```
$ hjson -j parse.json | jq '..|objects|select(.status) | .status, ._id, .name'
"status"
218025408945123440000000
"djvbsdhvsdvasdv"
```